# Class method type

Tags: c++, numerical-recipes

I am writing a code using the numerical recipes library and I would like to minimize a function which is actually the method of a class. I have this type of code:

```
class cl{
  Doub instance(VecDoub_I &x)
  {
    return x[0]*x[0] + x[1]*x[1];
  };
};
```

And I want to minimize this function using the Powell method, in the following code

```
// enter code here
int main(void)
{
  cl test;
  Powell<Doub (VecDoub_I &)> powell(test.instance);
}
```

But when I compile I get the following error :

```
main.cpp:241:22: error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
main.cpp:242:54: error: no matching function for call to ‘Powell<double(const NRvector<double>&)>::Powell(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

Has anybody already ecountered this problem ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try typedef? `typedef Doub type_for_template (VecDoub_I &)` and later `Powell<type_for_template> powell(test.instance);`

Comment: @user2197372 1) Numerical-recipes are probably not the best way to go. 2) You look like you're calling an object of "Doub" - Do you reference this class?

Comment: The class Doub are classes which are used in the numerical recipes. Doub -> double; Vec_Doub_I is a constant vector of doubles

Comment: Just curious : can someone explain the meaning of this syntactic madness  please ? `Powell<Doub (VecDoub_I &)>`.

Comment: Powell is the class which I will use to minimise my function. this function takes a constant vecor as an argument a pointer to a constant vector of double which is typedef `VecDoub_I` in the nuerical recipes and the return type is `Doub`which is a typedef for double in the numerical recipes

Answer (score 0):

Since `cl::instance` is an *instance* method (i.e. not a static method) it requires a `this` pointer. Therefore you can't capture a pointer to it in a [regular function pointer](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types). Also in order to get the address of a function you should use the `&` operator.

I'm not familiar with the library you're using but I think changing the function to be `static` (or making it a free function) and adding the `&` should help.

```
Powell<Doub (VecDoub_I &)> powell(&cl::instance);
```